# I am trying to consume a PHP SOAP service from C# and create a class wrapper in VS 2010

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio, web-services, soap

I've been tasked with creating a class wrapper for a SOAP service, the idea is that you'll be able to treat it as a regular class. The main reason for this is that the WDSL for the SOAP service contains only one method and it's got 5 parameters and it's only kind of OO so you'd have to know all the method calls really well and it's a bit hard to remember them all.

OK, so I've tried adding a web reference, now web references can now be added as service references in VS 2010. You click add service reference advanced etc and it puts in a service reference. Great. Unfortunately if I try and access this from a class I can't.

I can build a console app and put code in the main procedure and access the method of the SOAP service fine but when I add a reference to a class library the intellisense won't allow me to select anything. I'd instantiate an instance like so:

```
SOAPService.webServiceService ws = new SOAPService.webserviceService();

ws.
```

and then the intellisense refuses to kick in. If I do the same in a web project or a console app then I can access it fine. I've added the namespace I've done all kinds of things. Also, I can add a web reference and get a DISCO file whenever I create a web project.

OK, also while I'm on the subject I also need to pass credentials to the web service in PHP.

The problem is that in the past I'd create some .net system credentials and add these and it would usually pass through if I was connecting to another .net service.

How should I be sending them to a PHP web service? I always get either invalid username/password combo errors or envelope malformatted error types

Thanks
Mr. B

Answer (score 0):

So the intellisense is not working, but if you add the method in and try to use it does it work, or produce an error?

With regard to diagnosing authentication issues try using fiddler to view the SOAP messages that are being sent, and to view the reply. Do you have some other software that connects and authenticates to that service? Use fiddler to look at the SOAP messages and compare them to see if the header is different etc.

I'd normally do it like this,

```
using (Service service = new Service())
{
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "domain";
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
}
```

Also with regard to the service working or not in general use fiddler if you have any problems, you can see the SOAP messages and it often gives you a clearer message.

I know in IIS you can turn on failed request handling that also gives you an insight from what is going on at the server end, perhaps you have some form of logging too for your php service?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not actually running the PHP service myself. I do have a fully formatted response with the error in now as I've taken a slightly different tact and am now manually calling the service rather than using a web reference as I think I may have more control (there's only one method for the soap service so I don't really have a problem with this).

The guy who wrote the service has given me the following code in PHP to demonstrate how to use the service. The problem I now have is that I don't really understand the object arraty

Comment: oop's pressed return. I don't understand what the array he's passing with the request. try
{
                $oClient = new SoapClient("http://xxxxxxxxxxx/webservice/xxxxxxx/webservice.php?wsdl",
                array(
                                'trace'                    => 1, 
                                'exceptions'        => true,
                                'login'         => "xxxxxxxxx",
                                'password'      => "xxxxxxxxx"                      

));     

Does anybody out there know where this array goes in the SOAP message?